# Performance (not space) differences between storing dates in DATE vs. VARCHAR fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

We have a MySQL-based system that stores date values in `VARCHAR(10)` fields, as SQL-format strings (e.g. `'2021-09-07'`).

I am aware of the large additional space requirements of using this format over the native `DATE` format, but I have been unable to find any information about performance characteristics and how the two formats would differ in terms of speed.  I would assume that working with strings would be slower for non-indexed fields.  However, if the field is indexed I could imagine that the indexes on string fields could potentially yield much larger improvements than those on date fields, and possibly even overtake them in terms of performance, for certain tasks.

Can anyone advise on the speed implications of choosing one format over the other, in relation to the following situations (assuming the field is indexed):

- Use of the field in a `JOIN` condition
- Use of the field in a `WHERE` clause
- Use of the field in an `ORDER BY` clause
- Updating the index on `INSERT`/`UPDATE`

I would like to migrate the fields to the more space-efficient format but want to get some information about any potential performance implications (good or bad) that may apply.  I plan to do some profiling of my own if I go down this route, but don't want to waste my time if there is a clear, known advantage of one format over the other.

Note that I am also interested in the same question for `VARCHAR(19)` vs. `DATETIME`, particualrly if it yields a different answer.

Comment: Please share more details. I would assume that any performance differences hardly rely on the kind of comparisons you are using (only equality? Larger than/greater than?)

Comment: DATE datatype operations are always faster. Reasons: a) DATE is binary compact format, the values can be compared by single processor command whereas string datatype needs in char-by-char or even byte-by-byte cyclic compare b) collation is applied to string comparing process whereas binary DATE does not need in this.

Comment: @Akina I am aware of those issues, and for non-indexed fields I can see a clear performance impact.  The reason I was wondering is that a B-Tree index on a string field may end up being more efficient when matching records than whatever type of index is used for dates.  For example, finding all records where `DateField = X` or where `DateField BETWEEN x AND y`....

Comment: ...The way the underlying indexes are implemented will make the difference here, and I could imagine an indexed string lookup being `O(10)` (i.e. checking 10 nodes in a B-Tree to find all matching records) as opposed to `O(n)` (where `n` is the number of records), for an unindexed DATE field where each row needs to be compared.  The question is how much the date indexing improves on this.

Comment: @NicoHaase I guess my question relates to comparison that can make use of the indexes as I assume that `DATE` would win on any comparison that doesn't use the index (except, probably, if you end up doing string comparisons for some wierd reason).

Comment: @HappyDog - why do you assume indexing a date value will somehow be wildly inefficient compared to doing the same with strings? It's a compact format with well defined ordering. Trying to write a check constraint on that string, if your engine even supports them, such that you can't store `2021-02-29` in there is also problematic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I don't assume that.  I assume that indexed strings are faster than *unindexed* dates for operations which use the index.  The point of my question is to understand whether there are situations where indexed strings are faster than *indexed* dates, which seems unlikely but is heavily dependent on the implementation of date indexing.  I am looking to get some evidence to back this up, one way or another.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I would assume that *if* the current implementation of indexes on actual dates would be slower than using indexes on string dates, that the developers would just implement indexes on dates by using string dates.

Answer (score 0):

Additional space *is* a performance issue.  Databases work by reading data pages (and index pages) from disk.  Bigger records require more data pages to store.  And that has an effect on performance.

In other words, your date column is 11 bytes versus 4 bytes.  If you had a table with only ten date columns, that would be 110 bytes versus 40, that would require almost three times as much time to scan the data.

As for your operations, if you have indexes that are being used, then the indexes will also be larger.  Because of the way that MySQL handles collations for columns, comparing string values is (generally) going to be less efficient than comparing binary values.

Certain operations such as extracting the date components are probably comparable (a string function versus a date function).  However, other operations such as extracting the day of the week or the month name probably require converting to a date and then to a string, which is more expensive.

Comment: *In other words, your date column is 11 bytes versus 4 bytes ... that would require almost three times as much time to scan the data.* In fact, this is too abstract reasoning. It is necessary to look at the size of the record, and not at the size of one field. The larger the record size, the smaller the effect. Moreover, it is necessary to look not even at the size of the record, but at the number of records that fits on one storage unit (page). And it may turn out that these 7 bytes of difference do not affect the size that the table occupies on disk at all.

Comment: @AKina . . . Read the entire paragraph.

Comment: Simply I cannot imagine the table which contains 10 columns with dates only...

Answer (score 0):

More bytes being compared --> slightly longer to do the comparison.

More bytes in the column --> more space used --> slightly slower operations because of more bulk on disk, in cache, etc.

This applies to either 1+10 or 1+19 bytes for `VARCHAR` versus 3 for `DATE` or 5 for `DATETIME`.  The "1" is for the 'length' of `VARCHAR`; if the strings are a consistent length, you could switch to `CHAR`.

A BTree is essentially the same whether the value is an Int, Float, Decimal, Enum, Date, or Char.  `VARCHAR` is slightly different in that it has a 'length'; I don't see this is a big issue in the grand scheme of things.

The number of rows that need to be fetched is the most important factor in the speed of a query.  Other things, such as datatype size, come further down the list of what slows things down.

There are lots of `DATETIME` functions that you won't be able to used.  This *may* lead to a table scan instead of using an `INDEX`.  That would have a big impact on performance.  Let's see some specific SQL queries.

Using `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin` for your date/datetime columns would make comparisons slightly faster.